# How can I install GNOME LaTeX on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gnome, latex

LaTeXila, now [GNOME LaTeX](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GNOME-LaTeX), is my favorite LaTeX editor on GNOME, but unfortunately its package on Ubuntu/Debian is outdated: it provides LaTeXila 3.22.0 instead of GNOME LaTeX 3.38.

A problem with dependencies, apparently now solved, seems to be the reason for that: *[New upstream version 3.28 (#910573)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=910573)*

Is there a way to install the latest version of GNOME LaTeX on Ubuntu? What are the step-by-step instructions for how to compile it?

Comment: The [Debian Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/latexila) shows a few other problems, though none seem to be blockers. The volunteer maintainer seems to be [very busy](https://udd.debian.org/dmd/?tanguy%2Bdebian%40ortolo.eu#todo) with other packages. Debian software gets updated when volunteers (like you) step up to learn how to package, how to maintain those packages, and how to spread the work so everybody's load is lighter. If you want to help be part of the solution that makes LaTeXila available to everybody, start your journey at http://mentors.debian.net

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, I am aware of the complex and time consuming work many volunteers shoulder to maintain packages and I didn't mean to blame anybody for that particular package being out of date. I am afraid however becoming a maintainer is out of my scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installation of GNOME LaTeX maybe done while combining [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/blob/packages/gnome-latex/trunk/PKGBUILD) with knowledge of Ubuntu.

At first we need to enable Source Code repositories (*`deb-src`*) from Software and Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then update package lists and install all necessary build-dependencies for current LaTeXila version and its newer variant:

```
sudo apt-get update
# for current
sudo apt-get build-dep latexila 
# for the newest
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-4-dev libamtk-5-dev libtepl-5-dev libdconf-dev valac gobject-introspection gtk-doc-tools
```

Then download latest tarball by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.gnome.org/sources/gnome-latex/3.38/gnome-latex-3.38.0.tar.xz
tar -xf gnome-latex-3.38.0.tar.xz
cd gnome-latex-3.38.0

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gtk-doc
make -j$(nproc)
```

Then finally create local deb-package for the GNOME LaTeX application using [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall):

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall

sudo checkinstall
# for "Should I create a default set of package docs?  [y]:" press <y>, <Enter>
# for description enter "GNOME LaTeX" and then hit <Enter> then <Ctrl>+<D>
# for "This package will be built according to these values:" hit <Enter>
# hit <Enter> until deb-package created and installed
```

and enjoy

> [image: GNOME LaTeX 3.38 on Ubuntu MATE 21.10]